# Is it possible to insert icons on folders with the "gio set" command?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, icons, gvfs

On `Ubuntu 16.04` I used the following command to insert icons on my folders and it worked fine:

```
gvfs-set-attribute -t string folderIWishToInsertIcon metadata::custom-icon "file:///home/myUser/myIcon.png"
```

After upgrading to `Ubuntu 18.04` this command still works fine but now I receive a message saying that it's a deprecated tool and it recommends me to use `gio set` instead :

```
ramuyko@myPC:~$ gvfs-set-attribute -t string folderIWishToInsertIcon metadata::custom-icon "file:///home/myUser/myIcon.png"
This tool has been deprecated, use 'gio set' instead.
See 'gio help set' for more info.
```

I've seen [gio](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/gio.1.html)'s man page and tried to insert icons on my folders with the `gio set` command but I didn't succeed using the right parameters. Does anyone know if it's possible and how to do it?

Comment: What parameters exactly did you use ?

Comment: Try `gio set -t 'string'  folderIWishToInsertIcon 'metadata::custom-icon'  'file:///home/myUser/myIcon.png'`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Ah, my bad... It works using the exact same parameters of gvfs-set-attribute like you said. I was trying to recreate the line from zero reading the man page and it didn't cross my mind to change only the command. Well, now I know how to use a new command at least... :)

Comment: Very well !  Want to post an answer with the proper command ? Or should I convert my comment into one ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Just converting your comment into one is fine for me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As solved in the comments, `gio set` command uses same form of parameters that the `gvfs-set-attribute` uses, except `set` in `gio` is a separate command-line parameter, instead of `gvfs-set-attribute` being one whole comman. Thus the proper command should be:

```
gio set -t 'string' folderIWishToInsertIcon 'metadata::custom-icon' 'file:///home/myUser/myIcon.png'
```