# Ubuntu 18.04 : Setting attribute metadata::custom-icon not supported

Tags: nautilus, 18.04, icons

I tried following the steps in [this] ([Is it possible to insert icons on folders with the "gio set" command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044358/is-it-possible-to-insert-icons-on-folders-with-the-gio-set-command))

However, when I run the command I get
`Setting attribute metadata::custom-icon not supported`

Is there a configuration I have incorrect or some package that is missing?

I am trying to set an icon on a folder and it isn't working.

[Update:  I can set it using the Nautilus properties dialog, but wondering where this is set now if not on metadata::custom-icon?]