# gio: Setting attribute metadata::custom-icon not supported

Tags: deb

On Ubuntu 22.4 lts I can manually assign an icon to an executable file in nautilus, by right clicking on that file in the file explorer, select "Properties", click on the default icon, and select a new icon file.

After I've done that `gio info <filename>`
gives me `metadata::custom-icon: file:///my-icon.png`
So far so good.

But when I try to set the icon via gio like this

`gio set -t 'string' "${FILE_PATH}" metadata::custom-icon "file://${ICON_PATH}"`

I get an error

`gio: Setting attribute metadata::custom-icon not supported`

metadata:custom-icon should be writeable by gio, as

`gio info -w <filename>`

shows me

`Writable attribute namespaces: metadata (string, Copy with file, Keep with file when moved)`

I want to use this as part of a postinst script for my deb package. Other metadata values also won't work, like metadata::trust etc.

I know, this Question has been asked before, but I haven't found a solution for this problem yet.

Comment: Seems what ever it is your are trying to is simply not supported. Have you looked at this question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044358/is-it-possible-to-insert-icons-on-folders-with-the-gio-set-command

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered you problem, got the same error. At last I found there were different "gio" in my Ubuntu. The one that report `metadata::custom-icon not supported` was `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/gio`, which was provided by annaconda3.

And there was another `/usr/bin/gio` provided by apt-get, which worked for me.

To discover which one of "gio" you are using, just type `which gio` in bash to find out. To fix the problem:

Change $PATH to use system provided gio, or
use absolute path of `/usr/bin/gio`.
Hope that works for you.